Ubuntu Software gets stuck on the Installed tab screen in Ubuntu 22.04
I can't access the Installed tab in Ubuntu Software to inspect what software I have installed.
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my PC. This morning I wanted to check what software I have installed, so I clicked the Ubuntu Software icon. Then I clicked the Installed tab, and it got stuck at the waiting screen. No list of software showed up, just a circle that kept on turning.


Can you access the Internet from this computer? Open a terminal and enter the command apt list --installed. Then copy the output and paste it in your question. Format the pasted output as code by using the {_} icon above the edit window.

yes my computer is connect to internet now
but i need to go to 'installed' windows so i can uninstall some of the software/apps i have installed

how do i copy the output?  do i screenshot it?

Scroll up. Select all the text with mouse. Right click and select copy.

Multiple ways: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages I like to add to my rsync backup script these, so backup has current list: sudo /usr/bin/apt-mark showmanual > manual.txt and sudo dpkg --get-selections > all_files.txt

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu Software not loading properly
